# React Kendo Treeview scroll to item

Tags: reactjs, typescript, kendo-ui, treeview

I am using React Kendo Treeview UI. I want to try to scroll to the item that is selected in the tree. I found many examples for Javascript and JQuery but none for React version. I couldn't solve this problem by playing around with it.

Items in the tree are of type `MyViewTreeModel`. I have a `selectOntree` method that finds a node and set the selected to true. My problem is I want to scroll to that item.

```
export interface MyViewTreeModel {
    text: string,
    expanded: boolean,
    employeeId : number,
    treeId: number,
    items?: MyViewTreeModel [],
    selected: boolean
}
```

....

```
<TreeView 
            data={myData}
            expandIcons={true}
            onExpandChange={onExpandChange}
            onItemClick={OnItemClick}
            aria-multiselectable={false}
            aria-label={'text'}                
   ></TreeView>
```

....

```
const selectOnTree = (employeeId: number ) => {            
            let treeItem = recursivelyFindEmployeeInTree(myData[0], employeeId);
            treeItem.selected = true;
            forceUpdate();                         
        }
    }
```

`myData` is of type `MyViewTreeModel` .
One solution I tried : I added `ref?: any` to my model and tried `treeItem.ref.current.focus();` in selectOnTree function, but ref was `undefined`.

Another solution I tried is adding this property to TreeView:

```
ref={component => treeViewRef.current = component}
```

Then tried this just to select the first 'li' tag in the TreeView:

```
            if(!_.isNil(treeViewRef.current)            ){
                let domElement = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(treeViewRef.current);
                let treeItemDom = domElement.firstChild.firstChild;
                (treeItemDom as HTMLElement).focus();
            }
```

This didn't work, it doesn't put the focus at that point.

I am thinking maybe I should define a custom itemRender that has a ref that I can find the `offsetTop` of it, but then there are more than one item, how can I create a different ref for each one? Or maybe a custom ItemRender that renders an input (with css I can make it look like a span) and then set `autofocus` to `true` if selected is true. Not sure if `autofocus` true make it scroll to that item.

Comment: Can you put your code somewhere what have you been tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I could find to make it work:

1. Adding a reference to TreeView

   `let treeViewRef = useRef(null);`

In return statement:

```
    <TreeView 
            data={myData}
            expandIcons={true}
            onExpandChange={onExpandChange}
            onItemClick={OnItemClick}
            aria-multiselectable={false}
            aria-label={'text'} 
            ref={component => treeViewRef.current = component}></TreeView>
```

2.Defined this function to scroll to a specific treeItem:
'k-in' is the className for each span that represent each item in the Kendo Treeview UI component.

```
    const scrollToTreeViewItem = (treeItem: MyViewTreeModel ) => {
        if(!_.isNil(treeViewRef.current)){
            let domElement = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(treeViewRef.current);
            let treeItemDoms = (domElement as Element).querySelectorAll('.k-in');
            let domArray = [];
            treeItemDoms.forEach((node) => {
                domArray.push(node as HTMLElement);
            });
            let targetedDomElement = domArray.find((item) => {
                return item.innerText === treeItem.text;
            });
            targetedDomElement.scrollIntoView();
        }
    }
```